# Delayed durability - can data loss be prevented in case of crash

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

This book suggests that 
"Data loss is possible with delayed durability because you might lose committed transactions. If SQL Server crashes after a transaction commits, but before the 60KB buffer is filled, that transaction cannot be recovered because it is lost."

However wont the transactions be available on the transaction log and can be replayed for recovery?

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5Es3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT159&lpg=PT159&dq="data+loss+is+possible+with+delayed+durability"&source=bl&ots=Mwmh4cKa6G&sig=tctRb18itYQyBxo7lLhkT1w4-z4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAyau784jeAhWHMo8KHW1XCi4Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q="data%20loss%20is%20possible%20with%20delayed%20durability"&f=false

Comment: I see most of your questions are based on the doubts that you have with 1 book. Have you tried to look around e.g. blog posts to help answer/clear your doubts ?  E.g. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/delayed-durability-sql-server-2014/ and https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/io-subsystem/delayed-durability-in-sql-server-2014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you enable delayed durability, transactions aren't written to the transaction log file before they are committed.

That's why transactions aren't available in the log, and they will be permanently lost in that scenario.

Comment: Isnt the delay is to write to the disk? Instead of to the log?

Comment: @variable the log file IS on disk. That's where it lives. I think you're misunderstanding the difference between the log file and the data pages. SQL Server has never held up transactions to write to the data pages (MDF/NDF files) - those are written asynchronously long after the transaction finishes.

Comment: Sorry I meant that: the delay is to write to the data page (disk). I thought it immeidately write to the transaction log as usual. I thought the delay was to write the changes to the data page. Is my understsnding incorrect?

Comment: @variable Brent's answer is short, but accurate. If you want a more detailed answer, check out the links that Kin posted in the comments on your question. (This https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/io-subsystem/delayed-durability-in-sql-server-2014 and this https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/delayed-durability-sql-server-2014/). The whole point of delayed durability is that it delays writing your transaction to disk AT ALL--not even in the transaction log. Hence the **durability** of your transaction being **delayed**.

Comment: @variable no, your understanding is not correct. Delayed Durability means your transaction is considered committed immediately, even before the log file is written to disk.